# What is the easiest way to learn how to connect to LDAP using c# outside of a domain?

Tags: ldap, nservicebus, domainservices, activedirectorymembership

Is there a way that I can host a light weight version of LDAP on my developer box, so I can test out scenarios like creating a new domain account when a new employee is hired.

I am building an IT Service using NServiceBus that subscribes to a "NewEmployeeHired" message. When an employee is hired I need to be able to create a domain account for that employee that is activated on their start date.

I have very little experience with creating domain accounts via c#, so I would like to have a light weight environment where I can learn to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (or AD-LDS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897400.aspx), formerly know as ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode), exists for just this kind of situation (and more, of course).